# Turning ID into Unique Sound with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to turn my UUID into unique sounds using FFMPEG, but I am unsure how to do this.

So right now I have UUID that look like this: '1e859915-bcdf-4862-8af2-bb43f04e2158'

Like UUID are unique, I want to make them all each into unique 1-2 second audio files. Can FFMPEG do this or is there a different route? Is something the the SINE function in FFMPEG would do or something else?

Comment: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i flite=text=1e859915-bcdf-4862-8af2-bb43f04e2158:voice=slt -filter:a atempo=2` :)

Comment: This depends on what sort of audio you want to generate. Audio that people can easily distinguish? Tags easy for a program to read? Sounds that can be played, recorded with added noise, and still decoded? Musically pleasing sounds? Without knowing that, I don't think we can be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to turn each nibble in the GUID into a tone in the range `A4-C6`.

It outputs unsigned 8-bit PCM in [WAVE](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/), no `ffmpeg` required. The code is for illustrative purposes only, feel free to add proper validation etc.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* out;
    int duration = 2; // [s]
    int32_t rate = 44100; // [Hz]
    uint8_t guid[] = {0x1e, 0x85, 0x99, 0x15, 0xbc, 0xdf, 0x48, 0x62, 0x8a, 0xf2, 0xbb, 0x43, 0xf0, 0x4e, 0x21, 0x58};
    int32_t samples_per_nibble = (float) duration / 32 * rate;
    int32_t total_samples = samples_per_nibble * 32;
    int16_t c16;
    int32_t c32;

    if ((out = fopen("test.wav", "wb")) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    // WAV header
    // ChunkID
    fputs("RIFF", out);
    // ChunkSize
    c32 = 36 + total_samples;
    fwrite(&c32, 4, 1, out);
    // Format
    fputs("WAVE", out);
    // Subchunk1ID
    fputs("fmt ", out);
    // Subchunk1Size
    c32 = 16;
    fwrite(&c32, 4, 1, out);
    // AudioFormat
    c16 = 1;
    fwrite(&c16, 2, 1, out);
    // NumChannels
    c16 = 1;
    fwrite(&c16, 2, 1, out);
    // SampleRate
    c32 = rate;
    fwrite(&c32, 4, 1, out);
    // ByteRate
    c32 = rate;
    fwrite(&c32, 4, 1, out);
    // BlockAlign
    c16 = 1;
    fwrite(&c16, 2, 1, out);
    // BitsPerSample
    c16 = 8;
    fwrite(&c16, 2, 1, out);
    // Subchunk2ID
    fputs("data", out);
    // Subchunk2Size
    c32 = total_samples;
    fwrite(&c32, 4, 1, out);

    // Data
    for (int b = 0; b < 16; b++) {
        // for each byte in the GUID
        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
            // for each nibble
            uint8_t nibble = (n ? guid[b] >> 4 : guid[b]) & 0x0f;
            // go nibble steps above A4
            float frequency = 440.0 * pow(1.059463094359, nibble);
            // write the samples
            for (int s = 0; s < samples_per_nibble; s++) {
                int sample = (sin(frequency * 2 * M_PI * s / rate) + 1) * 0.5 * 255;
                fputc(sample, out);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```